# Which girl is Dr West referring to?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, dr-strange-multiverse-of-madness

At a wedding scene in *Doctor Strange in the Multiverse of Madness* (2022), Dr. West sits beside Dr. Strange and mentions not seeing him
for a while. Dr. Strange replies that he was affected by Thanos’ snap. Dr. West
shares that he lost his cats and brother while he was gone. Dr. Strange expresses
condolences. Dr. West wonders if things had to happen that way and if there was
another path. Dr. Strange replies that it was the only option they had, to which
Dr. West agrees:

> Dr West: The best surgeon and the best superhero. But you still didn't get **the girl**.

I thought Dr. West was referring to America Chavez, but in the next scene, it became clear that **Dr. Strange was not familiar with who America Chavez was**.

Which girl is Dr West referring to?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

TLDR: The girl that he didn't get was Christine.

They meet at the wedding of Christine Palmer.
She had been the love interest of Stephen Strange and one recurring theme throughout the complete movie is that he still misses her and wants to be with her.

His "other ego" *Sinister Strange* even says later that he searched all the multiverse but could not find ONE where he and Christine are together as you can read in the [transcript](https://movies.fandom.com/wiki/Doctor_Strange_in_the_Multiverse_of_Madness/Transcript) of the movie (emphasis of mine):

> **Sinister Stephen Strange**: Are you happy, Stephen?
> **Strange**: What?
> **Sinister Stephen Strange**: Are you happy, Stephen? It's the question that... Christine Palmer asked me at her wedding. I said, yes, of course, I'm happy. I'm a sorcerer with the power of gods. What man wouldn't be happy? Then I, came back to this god darn haunted house. Sat down... and wondered why I'd lied. I never meant for any of this to happen. **I was looking for a world where things were different. Where I had Christine**. Where I was... happy. **But I didn't find it**. All I found were more of us. So I did those Stephens a favor. You ever had that dream where you're falling, as if you've been pushed off a tall building? That was probably me. The Darkhold exacts a heavy toll.

So Strange did not "get the girl": She marries someone else...

Comment: So girl is Christine ? In the MCU, are **women over 18** treated as girls?

Comment: yes, see my edit

Comment: @MichaelBevans get the girl is a common English idiom. It is also belittling in that it infantalises and removes agency from the woman who is the subject of the phrase, but is in general use and not MCU specific.

Comment: The word 'girl' is often used loosely to refer to human females of any age in other contexts outside of the specific phrase "get the girl." For example, the term "girlfriend" and the phrase "You go, girl" aren't used exclusively to refer to minors. There was a famous TV sitcom titled "[The Golden Girls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Girls)," the subjects of which were far from being minors. Similarly, the term 'boys' is sometimes used loosely to refer to adult men.